# How to import a CMake project to Eclipse and make it work with EGit

Tags: eclipse, cmake, egit, freecad

I'm trying to use Eclipse to work with FreeCAD project.

I'm following these instructions as they seem to match my situation:

http://www.mantidproject.org/Setting_up_Eclipse_projects_with_CMake

What I've done:

I checked out the FreeCAD project from Github:

https://github.com/FreeCAD

to my home folder with:

```
mkdir ~/FreeCAD
cd ~/FreeCAD
git clone https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD FreeCAD-git
```

I then created a build folder:

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

I then ran CMake like this:

```
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DECLIPSE_CDT4_GENERATE_SOURCE_PROJECT=TRUE ../FreeCAD-git
```

In Eclipse I did 'Import Existing Project...' and pointed the import wizard to the build folder and it duly created the .cproject and .project files there.

The project displays just fine in the Package Explorer but there is no '>' mark next to the project name to indicate that it is associated with a git repo.

If right click on the project and select 'Team' there are only two options in the submenu (`Apply Patch...` / `Share Project...^), a further indication that EGit has not picked up the git repo.

I the GitRepo view I can view the repo and work with it but because the project is not 'associated' with it I cannot commit or do 'anything git' with the project files.

If try '`Team/Share Project...`' and point the share project wizard  to the git repo it complains:

```
 Cannot move project FreeCAD_trunk@build to target location /Users/nyholku/FreeCAD/FreeCAD-git/FreeCAD_trunk@build, as this location overlaps with location /Users/nyholku/FreeCAD/FreeCAD-git, which contains a .project file
```

So I'm at loss how make EGit recognise the `/Users/nyholku/FreeCAD/FreeCAD-git/.git` repo.

Comment: Your question is unrelated to CMake and FreeCAD, please remove their tags.

Comment: Well, this poses the question what is the purpose of the tags?

Comment: To post questions that are related to CMake and FreeCAD. You have no problem with FreeCAD, but with your Eclipse plug-in egit.

Comment: Correct, however, some (possibly) many people may have the same problem with FreeCAD and the tag might them to find this post and we find a solution then it would help them, no?

Comment: These people probably will search with Google and not by tags. The tags are read by people interested in CMake and FreeCAD and are just noise to them.